# ORCAD - Oscillator startup

Tags: oscillator, orcad

I'm simulating an oscillator that I have designed for a 40kHz oscillation frequency. I simulated it in Orcad and I got a flat signal. After some research, I found that it's due to the program not calculating any noise or something to start the circuit.

[image: Circuit]

- I added an Ipulse to simulate noise - didn't work.
- Skipped initial bias point calculation - didn't work.

Do you have any idea how I can kick start my circuit ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In real life, transients and/or noise start oscillations in oscillators. In a simulation, everything is ideal and no noise is around. Furthermore, connecting dc Voltage source to your circuit and simulating, it most likely just goes to steady state and has no transient. Unfortunately that transient is what would kick start the oscillator if and only if the oscillator is properly designed and configured correct with proper values for gain. Too many times to say proper?

Fortunately there’s a way: replace your dc voltages with step voltage sources. They would be the same voltage value but have a step look to it with a rise time of 10ns should do it. Then view the output in transient mode. This usually works.

Comment: So i should put a Vpulse instead of my Vdc, going from 0V to 5V in 10ns at the start ?

Comment: Not a pulse, a step input. You can probably just use whatever rise and fall time they use as default. It steps from 0 to 5V and stays at 5V. Also change the 2.5 V to a step input of same value.

Comment: It doesn't work as it should. There is no step input in Orcad so I have to play with Vpulse to have something similar.
I don't know if I'm doing it right. Do you have the software ?

Comment: I never used PSpice before. If your software doesn’t have an actual step input then maybe you can use a switch between power and circuit shown in video here: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=MwSseZy3nvM

Comment: Also you can remove that pulse input.

Comment: Also I just realized that R1 and R2 are a problem. Those values as you have set give a gain of -0.0125. For an RC phase shift oscillator, you need at least a gain of 29. So try 1M ohm for R2 and 33k ohm for R1. Might have to vary R1 to get it just right.

Comment: Your last comment made my circuit work ! I don't have 50kHz but I just have to teak it to be 40kHz.  Thank you so much

Comment: To start such an oscillator it is sufficient to give any capacitor an initial condition (for example some millivolts) IC=5mV.

Comment: Yeah when I saw that R1 and R2 values I knew something wasn’t going to work there. Glad it works.